# Django bulk_create not working

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to pass a dict to bulk_create, but it is not working.  If someone has used this prior, I would appreciate advice.

**Django Server Model:**

```
class Servers(models.Model):
    name             = models.CharField(('name'), max_length=128)
    location         = models.OneToOneField('locations.Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_address       = models.CharField(('ip_address'), max_length=128)
    date             = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

**Django Location Model:**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(('city'), max_length=10)
    geolocation = models.PointField(('location'))
```

**A print of my dict:**

```
{
    'Florida': {
        'name' : 'server-a',
        'location':'Miami',
        'ip_address':'172.16.16.1',
    },
    'Colorado': {
        'name' : 'server-b',
        'location':'Denver',
        'ip_address':'172.16.24.1',
},
```

**My function:**

```
def add_to_db(data_dict):
    Servers.objects.bulk_create(Servers(**d) for d in data_dict.values())
```

**My error:**

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Florida'": "Server.location" must be a "Location" instance.
```

Comment: You need a key/object in your dict for location.

Comment: `location` field of Server model is in OneToOneField, it will not accept string value.

Answer (score 3):

Since `location` is OneToOne field you need to pass as `location` argument location object. Or you can pass `location_id` instead.
Change data to this:

```
{
    'Florida': {
        'name' : 'server-a',
        'location_id':1,
        'ip_address':'172.16.16.1',
    },
    'Colorado': {
        'name' : 'server-b',
        'location_id':2,
        'ip_address':'172.16.24.1',
},
```

Comment: New to Django: I take I could do d = Location.objects.filter(city="Miami"), but how can I only have location_id returned?

Comment: You can do this `miami_id = Location.objects.get(city="Miami").id`.